# Is there a Dart interface to Firestore - with API as in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This Firestore document

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Shows samples of 10+ languages but not Dart.

I found, there is a

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

which appears to be a Flutter packageinterfacing Firestore.
 Two questions:

1. Can the package in https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore be used from server side Dart, or does in depend on something in Flutter?
2. Is it's API equivalent to that described in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main plugins that allow you to access Firestore from Dart code:

1. The [FlutterFire plugin](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-library.html). Use this plugin if you're targeting iOS or Android with your Flutter app, as it is a wrapper around Firebase's native SDKs for those platforms.
2. The [`firebase-dart` plugin](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart). Use this plugin if you're targeting Web with your Flutter app.

There are no plugins that are more official than these two, as they are part of the Flutter and Firebase organizations respectively.

Comment: The first link you listed is a link to documentation to the firestore library. The second link to firebase-dart is link to the plugin used to access firebase from Dart - correct so far? I assume firebase-dart also has apis to firestore? The link I provided, https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore  is a link to a pub package called "cloud-firestore". I cannot figure oacut how it relates to firebase-dart in your link. Could you comment - thanks

Comment: The link you provided is #1 in my answer. Since that only targets iOS and Android (by wrapping the native Firebase SDKs for those platforms) and you're targeting another platform, it won't work for you.

Comment: Ok thanks. Sounds like the discussed plugins and links cannot be used by Dart (on server) to Firestore. I will accept your response

Comment: The second library is apparently pure Dart, so you might want to give it a try on your server-side project.