# How to use cloud firestore in Flutter web app

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am creating a flutter web app ,I want to connect my flutter web project with cloud firestore, is there any to connect my project to cloud firestore

I have try import cloud_firestore: ^0.12.5+2 in pubspec.yaml.

Because op depends on cloud_firestore >=0.3.0 which requires the Flutter SDK, version solving failed.

Answer (score 5):

You can now use official [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) plugin in flutter web, just follow the instructions in readme page to integrate plugin.

Answer (score 4):

The [FlutterFire plugin](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-library.html) that you found only targets iOS or Android.

If you're targeting the web, use the [`firebase-dart` plugin](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart).

Also see a similar answer I gave yesterday here: [Is there a Dart interface to Firestore - with API as in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155885/is-there-a-dart-interface-to-firestore-with-api-as-in-https-firebase-google/57155947#57155947)

Comment: Thank you so much, is it possible for me to know how to config the firebase_dart plugin in flutter web ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the following dependency to your package manager:

```
cloud_firestore: 0.13.4
```

There are a couple of extra steps to take when configuring for web. These involve adding some script references to your index.html file with [Google's SDK reserved URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls)'s (this assumes you will be deploying to google hosting or at least serving locally for testing purposes).

```
<script src="/__/firebase/7.9.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.9.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.9.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

I previously wrote a step by step guide to [connecting a Flutter Web app to Google Cloud Firestore](https://medium.com/@mat_wright/connecting-a-flutter-web-form-to-google-cloud-firestore-f6bf7aa28f99), including an example contact form.

**Refs :**

https://medium.com/@mat_wright/connecting-a-flutter-web-form-to-google-cloud-firestore-f6bf7aa28f99

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls

[enter link description here](https://blog.matwright.dev/2020/03/03/creating-a-google-cloud-firestore-contact-form-for-flutter-web-apps/)

Comment: Your "step-by-step guide" is behind a pay-wall. Please update link to guide that does not require a subscription.

Comment: @MaxZ here you go: https://blog.matwright.dev/2020/03/03/creating-a-google-cloud-firestore-contact-form-for-flutter-web-apps/

Comment: @malwr thank you. Some of the code is unclear to me as to how it's added, do you have a link to your .dart file(s) / on your Github?

Answer (score 0):

For configuring Firestore and Firebase for Flutter Web this link will help a lot. I have tried to document all the steps required to configure: [Configure Firestore & Firebase with Flutter Web](https://medium.com/@priyanshjain301/for-flutter-web-configure-firebase-and-firestore-step-by-step-2022-30ade2a69102)

Answer (score -1):

maybe you need add 
dependencies:
  firebase_web: ^5.0.9
to your pubspec.yaml.
this page can help you https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_web